# Onmouseover for image

Tags: jquery, image

I was wondering how can I setup a voting system that comes up on an image when the mouse is hovered over them.

For example lets say look at the images on this widget http://jsfiddle.net/4B2Bc/. I was wondering when the user hovers their mouse over the image a thumbs up or thumbs down is shown, which can be used for voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a lot easier if you use jQuery! Instead of writing the script from scratch you can just use a plugin for jQuery.

If you want to enlarge the image when a user click on it, then take a look at this for example: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

You just load jQuery and prettyPhoto and add something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").prettyPhoto();
});
```

Then all your images will open in a box when you click on them.

I am also sure that you can find a voting plugin somewhere on the web for jQuery. Very easy!

And if you don't find one, you can alwasy write it yourself ;-)

Comment: upvote for you....I have no problem writing the voting plugin. What I was wondering is how to get the voting links or images to be display on mouseover on the image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4B2Bc/ I want to display a thumbs up and thumbs down image with links on each image on mouseover. I have written the voting system already, but its getting the voting links in the actual widget over each image, which only show up when the mouse is over the images.

Comment: I dont know if i quite understand, but maby you can use this http://www.ferretarmy.com/files/jQuery/ImageOverlay/ImageOverlay.html and just display the up and down thumbs in the overlay?

Comment: what I mean is lets say you have an image. When you move your mouse over the image (not click it) an upvote and a downvote icon show up near to the bottom of the image. When you move your mouse away from the image they fade away again and leaving the image transparent.

Comment: I guess you should take a look at jQuery's fade functions and write your own function to display the images and so on. http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=fade. Good luck :)